# Can I burn the Ubuntu ISO CD image onto a DVD to install it?

Tags: installation, dvd

I downloaded Ubuntu 11.10 and I want to burn it but I don't have a CD I only have DVDs, can I burn  it on a DVD and install it? cause I've googled it and some people said that it's not working but with older versions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've always burned to a DVD. It will work just fine, so long as your burner can burn DVDs and the computer you are installing to (if different from the burner) can read DVDs and boot from CD/DVD drive.

Comment: Indeed, I've done this many times, and never had problems. If the target machine supports booting from them, you could even burn the CD image to a Blu-Ray disc. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have always used k3b and occasionally receive a pop-up asking if I want to do it, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can, but I would get CDs just in case. (Says the guy installing Ubuntu 11.04 in a VM)